# what is the keycode of ":" in chrome

Tags: javascript, ascii

I have a problem in chrome to know what is the keycode of ":", I found that keycode 59 work in Firefox but not in chrome.

Is there any difference between keycodes according to browsers ? and can you give me or where to find this keycode working in chrome ?

Comment: Are you retrieving a keycode in a `keypress` or `keydown/up` handler?

Comment: That's strange, it should be 58 in all browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Virtual_key_codes

Comment: I want to use it with keypress @Teemu
No, it's 59 for me in Firefox :(

Comment: `e.which` gives me `58` when hitting `:` (semicolon (`;`) seems to give `59`) in [FF24](http://jsfiddle.net/3eDsn/)...?!

Comment: Yes, it works in this example but not for me. I have used this code for : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2403024/1295861

Answer (score 0):

[Please check this one in chrome](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_keycode)

This might help you....
Its showing like "186"

Comment: The problem is the button of ":" has 2 caracter ( ":" and "/" ), how I can determinate who's I've clicked ? ( I'm a windows client )